# scrollview warning

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

i made a simple test for an android app to ScrollView a TextView, almost there are no errors but i get a Warning ( This ScrollView layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless) and i dont know what to do . i wish i get your help

```
here is the code:

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hi"/>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a second to think about it! If the linear layout takes up all the space it could take up (say 200x400 pixels), then the Scroll view takes up as much space as the linear layout can take up (200x400 pixels), then your linear layout has just become useless! (in theory)

Try to add more stuff after you scroll view -- this may make your warning go away

Comment: Or remove the linear layout and make your ScrollView as parent since, the scrollView contains only one TextView in above example. Right?

Comment: Yes, correct! I was thinking the linear layout in the future might house more views.

Comment: Thank you Richard Lee, its work i added more text after ScrollView and its really work

Comment: Your welcome, Shrikant's suggestion is correct also. The easiest way I make sure I don't make redundant views is to imagine the views in my head. In this case Scroll View and Linear Layout were identical size 100% of the time, so that is wasteful :) Glad I could help. best of luck

Answer (score 0):

should be the top most parent... Remove your LinearLayout from top ant you are done.